# Order of Alembic's autogenerated revision file

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have quite a convoluted database schema that I'm hoping to version using Alembic. I am using a `declarative_base` to create my models, and my `env.py` looks like:

```
from logging.config import fileConfig
import os
import sys
from alembic import context
from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config, pool

sys.path.append(os.getcwd())

from app import db, create_app, Base

config = context.config
fileConfig(config.config_file_name)

app = create_app()
config.set_main_option("sqlalchemy.url", app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"])

target_metadata = Base.metadata

def run_migrations_offline():
    """Run migrations in 'offline' mode.

    This configures the context with just a URL
    and not an Engine, though an Engine is acceptable
    here as well.  By skipping the Engine creation
    we don't even need a DBAPI to be available.

    Calls to context.execute() here emit the given string to the
    script output.

    """

    url = config.get_main_option("sqlalchemy.url")
    context.configure(url=url)

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


def run_migrations_online():
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """

    engine = engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section),
        prefix='sqlalchemy.',
        poolclass=pool.NullPool
    )
    connection = engine.connect()
    context.configure(connection=connection, target_metadata=target_metadata)

    try:
        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()
    finally:
        connection.close()

if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    run_migrations_online()
```

When I run the following:

```
alembic revision --autogenerate -m ''
```

To autogenerate the schema: It detects the correct tables:

```
/limbus/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py:1917: SAWarning: Setting backref / back_populates on relationship UserAccountVersion.version_parent to refer to viewonly relationship UserAccount.versions will be deprecated in SQLAlchemy 1.4, and will be disallowed in a future release.  viewonly relationships should not be mutated (this warning may be suppressed after 10 occurrences)
  (self, other),
/limbus/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py:1917: SAWarning: Setting backref / back_populates on relationship UserAccount.versions to refer to viewonly relationship UserAccountVersion.version_parent will be deprecated in SQLAlchemy 1.4, and will be disallowed in a future release.  viewonly relationships should not be mutated (this warning may be suppressed after 10 occurrences)
  (self, other),
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'address'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'siteinformation'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'useraccount'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'useraccount_version'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added index 'ix_useraccount_version_end_transaction_id' on '['end_transaction_id']'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added index 'ix_useraccount_version_operation_type' on '['operation_type']'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added index 'ix_useraccount_version_transaction_id' on '['transaction_id']'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'useraccounttoken'
  Generating /limbus/migrations/versions/9aa6e8b6781c_.py ...  done
```

However, when I attempt to upgrade - it complains about the useraccount table not existing. If I take a look at the autogenerated version file:

```
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.create_table('address',
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('created_on', sa.DateTime(), server_default=sa.text('now()'), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('updated_on', sa.DateTime(), server_default=sa.text('now()'), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('street_address_one', sa.String(length=256), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('street_address_two', sa.String(length=256), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('city', sa.String(length=128), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('county', sa.String(length=128), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('post_code', sa.String(length=20), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('country', sa.String(length=2), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('author_id', sa.Integer(), nullable=True),
    sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['author_id'], ['useraccount.id'], ),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id')
    )
    op.create_table('siteinformation',
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('created_on', sa.DateTime(), server_default=sa.text('now()'), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('updated_on', sa.DateTime(), server_default=sa.text('now()'), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('miabis_id', sa.String(length=128), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('acronym', sa.String(length=64), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('name', sa.String(length=128), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('description', sa.String(length=128), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('url', sa.String(length=128), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('address_id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('author_id', sa.Integer(), nullable=True),
    sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['address_id'], ['address.id'], ),
    sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['author_id'], ['useraccount.id'], ),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id')
    )
    op.create_table('useraccount',
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('created_on', sa.DateTime(), server_default=sa.text('now()'), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('updated_on', sa.DateTime(), server_default=sa.text('now()'), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('email', sa.String(length=320), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('password_hash', sa.String(length=256), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('title', sa.Enum('MRS', 'MISS', 'MS', 'MR', 'MX', 'PROF', 'DR', name='title'), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('first_name', sa.String(length=128), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('middle_name', sa.String(length=128), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('last_name', sa.String(length=128), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('account_type', sa.Enum('ADM', 'BIO', 'PRO', 'BOT', name='accounttype'), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('access_control', sa.Enum('ADM', 'MOD', 'PRI', 'VIE', 'BOT', name='accesscontrol'), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('is_locked', sa.Boolean(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('site_id', sa.Integer(), nullable=True),
    sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['site_id'], ['siteinformation.id'], ),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id'),
    sa.UniqueConstraint('email')
    )
    op.create_table('useraccount_version',
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), autoincrement=False, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('created_on', sa.DateTime(), server_default=sa.text('now()'), autoincrement=False, nullable=True),
    sa.Column('updated_on', sa.DateTime(), server_default=sa.text('now()'), autoincrement=False, nullable=True),
    sa.Column('email', sa.String(length=320), autoincrement=False, nullable=True),
    sa.Column('password_hash', sa.String(length=256), autoincrement=False, nullable=True),
    sa.Column('title', sa.Enum('MRS', 'MISS', 'MS', 'MR', 'MX', 'PROF', 'DR', name='title'), autoincrement=False, nullable=True),
    sa.Column('first_name', sa.String(length=128), autoincrement=False, nullable=True),
    sa.Column('middle_name', sa.String(length=128), autoincrement=False, nullable=True),
    sa.Column('last_name', sa.String(length=128), autoincrement=False, nullable=True),
    sa.Column('account_type', sa.Enum('ADM', 'BIO', 'PRO', 'BOT', name='accounttype'), autoincrement=False, nullable=True),
    sa.Column('access_control', sa.Enum('ADM', 'MOD', 'PRI', 'VIE', 'BOT', name='accesscontrol'), autoincrement=False, nullable=True),
    sa.Column('is_locked', sa.Boolean(), autoincrement=False, nullable=True),
    sa.Column('site_id', sa.Integer(), autoincrement=False, nullable=True),
    sa.Column('transaction_id', sa.BigInteger(), autoincrement=False, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('end_transaction_id', sa.BigInteger(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('operation_type', sa.SmallInteger(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('created_on_mod', sa.Boolean(), server_default=sa.text('false'), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('updated_on_mod', sa.Boolean(), server_default=sa.text('false'), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('email_mod', sa.Boolean(), server_default=sa.text('false'), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('password_hash_mod', sa.Boolean(), server_default=sa.text('false'), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('title_mod', sa.Boolean(), server_default=sa.text('false'), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('first_name_mod', sa.Boolean(), server_default=sa.text('false'), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('middle_name_mod', sa.Boolean(), server_default=sa.text('false'), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('last_name_mod', sa.Boolean(), server_default=sa.text('false'), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('account_type_mod', sa.Boolean(), server_default=sa.text('false'), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('access_control_mod', sa.Boolean(), server_default=sa.text('false'), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('is_locked_mod', sa.Boolean(), server_default=sa.text('false'), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('site_id_mod', sa.Boolean(), server_default=sa.text('false'), nullable=False),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id', 'transaction_id')
    )
    op.create_index(op.f('ix_useraccount_version_end_transaction_id'), 'useraccount_version', ['end_transaction_id'], unique=False)
    op.create_index(op.f('ix_useraccount_version_operation_type'), 'useraccount_version', ['operation_type'], unique=False)
    op.create_index(op.f('ix_useraccount_version_transaction_id'), 'useraccount_version', ['transaction_id'], unique=False)
    op.create_table('useraccounttoken',
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('created_on', sa.DateTime(), server_default=sa.text('now()'), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('updated_on', sa.DateTime(), server_default=sa.text('now()'), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('user_id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('token_hash', sa.String(length=256), nullable=False),
    sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['user_id'], ['useraccount.id'], ),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id')
    )
    # ### end Alembic commands ###
```

It looks like useraccounts is being generated AFTER the FK dependency is being made between other classes.

I've searched high and low, but I don't know how I'd go about fixing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best wishes.

Comment: It's rather typical, it generates migrations, sometimes in the right order, sometimes not, hence the "please adjust", you can just order it manually and upgrade, so you first create the table before you reference it. As far as I'm aware, there's no fix

Answer (score 2):

So, I realise I had a FK to Site.id in UserAccount, which is wrong in itself - but if you can use `use_alter` in the FK dependency so that the FK relationship is only created once the Sites table is created.